# Splitting pandas table based on the first row in Python

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have a pandas table:

```
Data   Years  Y
A      2001   3
A      2007   5
A      2002   8
A      2009   1
B      2001   8
В      2004   5
С      2004   4
С      2006   6
С      2005   9
```

How can I analyze all the data for A, B and C separately? 
For example, histogram of each `Data`per `Year`in one plot?
Should it be something with pivot table or not?

Comment: Interestingly your other "B" is a "CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER VE".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
print df
  Data  Years  Y
0    A   2001  3
1    A   2007  5
2    A   2002  8
3    A   2009  1
4    B   2001  8
5    B   2004  5
6    C   2004  4
7    C   2006  6
8    C   2005  9

df1 = df.pivot(index='Data', columns='Years', values='Y')
print df1
Years  2001  2002  2004  2005  2006  2007  2009
Data                                           
A       3.0   8.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   5.0   1.0
B       8.0   NaN   5.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
C       NaN   NaN   4.0   9.0   6.0   NaN   NaN
```

If you need count not `NaN` values, use [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.notnull.html) and then convert boolean `DataFrame` to `int` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
print df1.notnull().astype(int)
Years  2001  2002  2004  2005  2006  2007  2009
Data                                           
A         1     1     0     0     0     1     1
B         1     0     1     0     0     0     0
C         0     0     1     1     1     0     0
```

If you have duplicates data in column `Years`, you can use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) with `aggfunc`, e.g. `sum`. I have duplicates in row `2` and `3`:

```
print df
  Data  Years   Y
0    A   2001   3
1    A   2007   5
2    A   2002   8
3    A   2002  10
4    A   2009   1
5    B   2001   8
6    B   2004   5
7    C   2004   4
8    C   2006   6
9    C   2005   9

print df.pivot_table(index='Data', columns='Years', values='Y', aggfunc=sum)
Years  2001  2002  2004  2005  2006  2007  2009
Data                                           
A       3.0  18.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   5.0   1.0
B       8.0   NaN   5.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
C       NaN   NaN   4.0   9.0   6.0   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Glad can help you! Good luck!

Comment: one more question:) how can i put the sum of each Data per Year in Values? for example, A(2001) = 1, and so on?

Comment: Do you think count values? `A(2006) = 0`, `C(2006) = 1` Or sum - but then `A(2006) = 0`, `C(2006) = 6` ?

Comment: yep, just to count:)

Comment: Ok, answer was edited. Now you need concat both DataFrames together?

Comment: but what if its not bulean, i mean there are two A in 2002, for example?
No-no, i need only the second dataframe)